# CDC job still tracking changes done on table(enabled with CDC) SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, cdc, sql-job

I currently have CDC enabled on a table for tracking changes done, however while playing around with it. I found out that even though I disable the CDC capture jobs associated with the table, the CT table still tracks all the *INSERT* and *UPDATE* done on the table its tracking. I believe that its this capture job that captures changes since this job is always in *executing* state. So just wondering as to why it still captures even when disabled.

Is this expected? Is there anyway to disable CDC tracking on the table without using `sys.sp_cdc_disable_table`?

Also, while we are at it would just like to ask how to possibly induce an error to stop this job automatically since I'm trying to recreate an error that made the CDC job stop.

Comment: can you pls say how you tried to disable it?

Comment: Hi, disabled the job itself by just right clicking on the job name and then 'disable'

Comment: I am not sure sp_replcmds will be stopped as soon as sql job is stopped. Also try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx

Comment: Do you also have replication set up on this database? If so, the log reader agent will also process any CDC events it finds while reading the log.

Comment: No, but I have a replication on another database. Will that have any effect?